# How to get value from url

Tags: javascript

I have a url like "https://abcd.com/qa2/index.html"
How to get only qa2 in javascript?

```
 var parts: string[] = location.pathname.split('/');
            var paths:string[] = new Array();
            parts.forEach(function(item){  
                if (item) 
                    paths.push(item);    
            });  
            if(parts.length >=2)
               {
                 console.log(parts[0]);
               }
```

this is not giving me the result!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `location.pathname.split('/')?.[1]`